# You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands

Tags: javascript, angular

Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.

I installed angular cli version is 15 and node js version is 18. But I am getting this (Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.) error. Please resolve my issue

I uninstalled the cli and node. and re installed also but issue is not fxed.

Comment: Hello,
There is an mistake in your command. Could you share the command which you are trying to use

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I typed 'ng -v'. Try using 'ng version' instead. This worked for me.